# Sqlite3 WAL mode commit perfromance

Tags: sqlite

I have a `SQLite3` DB where I Insert each second one row of data (500 bytes per row)for each table (around 100 tables). After several minutes, In order to keep the DB size small, I also remove the last line in each table. Ao totally I insert 50K of data, and on the steady state I remove 50K of data. I wrap the inserts and deletions in a transaction, where each second I commit those transaction.

`WAL` mode is enabled, with `sync mode = NORMAL`. There is another process that occasionally performs read operation on the DB, but those are very fast.

I'm seeing a strange behaviour. Every several minutes, the commit command itself takes several seconds, while in other times it takes few milliseconds. I tried to play with the `wal_autocheckpoint` with no success.

It is worth mentioning that the filesystem is working on Linux software raid on Linux VM. Without the raid, the performance are better, but those "hiccups" still occur.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem, that the writer is delayed, or that read transactions are delayed during an autocheckpoint?

Comment: The problem is that the writer is delayed by several seconds randomly.  The reader is all good.